# Приложение с Holo темой вылетает

Tags: android, android-studio

В styles.xml прописав это:

```
...    
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
...
```

И прописав в билд gradle:

```
...
minSdkVersion 11 
...
```

Скомпилировав, запустив на устройстве с Android 7.1.2 происходит вылет приложения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что может быть такого и как решить эту проблему?
код активити:

```
package ru.veselcraft.openvk;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

}
```

**Решение:**
Вписать `...extends Activity...` вместо `...extends AppCompatActivity...` и `import android.app.Activity` вместо `import android.support.v7.app.Activit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо унаследовать класс активити от `android.app.Activity`. У ваc, наверное, `AppCompatActivity` или что-то подобное.

Comment: и действительно, сейчас скомпилирую и проверю

Comment: сразу выдал несколько ошибок: Error:(35, 36) error: cannot find symbol class Activity, Error:(37, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype, Error:(39, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super и Error:(40, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Comment: нет............

Comment: Вы добавьте код активити в вопрос

Comment: добавил........

Comment: там импорт не тот, нужен этот `import android.app.Activity`, а не `mport android.support.v7.app.Activity`

Comment: Добавляйте всё, что уже выяснено комментариях, прямо в ответ.

Comment: вопрос решен. приложение спокойно запускается